# Introduce a delay to allow printing of word doc to complete

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code to print a word document from vbscript

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Caption = "Test"
objWord.Visible = False

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\test.doc")

'now print to default printer
objDoc.PrintOut()

MsgBox("Finished!")

'close word application
objWord.Quit 0
```

I would like to remove the message box and have the script silently run and complete, but when the delay of the message box is removed, the script finishes before the document is printed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with a sleep command, like below. 1000 is one second, so adjust as needed. 200 might work well for your script.

```
WScript.Sleep 1000
```